# Regex stop at first occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like so `{!Hello} there, {!World}`. I need to match `{!Hello}` and `{!World}` and I have my regex like so

```
$text = '{!Hello} there, {!World}';
preg_match_all("/\{\!.+\}/",$text,$var);
```

The problem is it matches the whole thing from beginning to end. That obviously means it's not stopping at the first occurrence of `}` but rather the last one. How can I match those?

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention I can't use \w+ because the word in between the brackets may contain special characters. IT may be something like `{!Email__email@some.domain__IsInvalid}`. I need to match this whole thing

Comment: You can try `preg_match_all("/\{\![a-z]+\}/i",$text,$var);`

Comment: Yeah but the word can also be something like `{!Email__someemail@some.domain__IsInvalid}`. I need to match this whole thing

Comment: Add a `?` after `+` to make it ungreedy.

Comment: @HamZa Ok that worked partially. Now it's matching them separately but still doesn't match special characters within a word. What does that do exactly?

Comment: @php_nub_qq huh ? Special characters ? Can you provide an example ? `.` should match everything except newlines in your case.

Comment: @HamZa I provided an example in the [second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063960/regex-stop-at-first-occurance?noredirect=1#comment24675263_17063960). Guess I should add this to the question as well

Comment: @php_nub_qq It does work [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oT8dJ9).

Comment: @HamZa you are correct, I just didn't have it set up correctly. I'm terribly sorry for my mistake! Please answer so I can accept and +rep! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to match ungreedy:
`/\{\!.+?\}/`

```
$text = '{!Hello} there, {!World} foo {!Email__someemail@some.domain__IsInvalid}';
preg_match_all("/\{\!.+?\}/",$text,$var);
print_r($var);
```

You could also add the `U` modifier (note it's uppercase):
`/\{\!.+\}/U`

```
$text = '{!Hello} there, {!World} foo {!Email__someemail@some.domain__IsInvalid}';
preg_match_all("/\{\!.+\}/U",$text,$var);
print_r($var);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is: `/\{\![^\}]*\}/`

It looks for characteres that are not a `}`, between `{!` and `}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
`\{(\![^\{]+)\}`
```

In your pattern `.+` is a greedy and it will match `as much as possible`. For example:

In examples:

> **{!Hello} there, {!World}}**
>
> **{!Hello} there, {!World}}** dsad

bold part are the matches found by your regex.

In my pattern:

`[^\{]` this part is also present with `+` which means greedy but it i have restricted it match till the `{` due to `^` sign in character class.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/31z-rtu

```
preg_match_all("/\{\!.+?}/",$text,$var);
```

I misplaced the ? operator first.
PHP understands the ? operator, it does exactly what you ask for, it limits the matches to the first occurence.

Hih.

Comment: Please test your regex before posting it, this won't work at all, at least not the desired results of the OP.